# Deleting a digital signing certificate (.PFX file)

Tags: c#, .net, pfx, assembly-signing

I previously installed an incorrect .PFX file to sign assemblies. I now need to remove this in order to correct a build error. Is there anyway to remove the invalid signing certificate? I've tried removing it through the snap-in for certificate management, but Visual Studio still uses it to build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds that you may have confused things a little bit.
Reading your question, it seems that you want to remove the signing the assembly with a strong key file?
That key file is not stored in the Certificate Store in Windows, but rather as a file (usually within your project folder).
Go in to the settings of the project, under the Signing tab, uncheck the "Sign the assembly".

If your are indeed referring to code signing (`Authenticode`), then you probably have a custom build action that signs the assembly with the code signing certificate using SignTool.exe.

Comment: I was attempting to build a project in Visual Studio and was informed that a .pfx file could not be accessed because I needed to supply the password. I manually attempted to install the .PFX file by using sn.exe, but realized after that I had installed the wrong .pfx file. Now, the build succeeds but incorrectly signs the generated .DLL. I need to know how to remove what I did with sn.exe.

Comment: Well, Visual Studio doesn't sign anything unless told to do so. Simply delete the faulty .pfx file (if that's not needed anymore), generate a new one (could be done in the same tab I mentioned in my answer) and finally tell Visual Studio to use the new file (still in the same Tab). Furthermore, a .pfx file for strong signing doesn't need to be installed anywhere. It could happily reside on the file system.